# regular expression matching /admin/something not administrator

Tags: php, regex

Hi I want to match strings like `/admin/` or `/admin/something` or `/admin` but not `/administration` or `/administrator`. I wrote this regular expression:

```
$pattern = '%^/admin(/|/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?$%'
```

and it works, but it is something ugly. I want to know can it be written more cleaner and understandable?

Comment: Regex is **"ugly"**. Unless you do it without using regex. It'll stay **"ugly"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
$pattern = '%^/admin(/[\w-]*)?$%'
```

This will match any of:

- /admin
- /admin/
- /admin/foobar

Comment: should be noted that `.` matches a lot more than `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks very muxh, It is really nice I'll accept in 3 minutes :)

Comment: @Sinomai: True it does but I wasn't sure what OP meant by `something` so I kept dot.

Comment: @Sinomai I sould replace `.` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`

Comment: @user3061142: Answer updated. `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` can be shortened as `[\w-]`